# What are these TLOG files? Should these be part of my source control?

Tags: tortoisegit, team-explorer

I am new to source control.

I don't recall seeing these *TLOG* files before today. Here is what my repository now looks like in **Team Explorer**:

[image: Team Explorer]

And **TortoiseGit**:

[image: TortoiseGit]

Do I need these as part of my repository tracking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That are logs from Visual C++ compiler that should be never part of source control. Exclude them in git via [.gitignore](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/visualstudio,c++):

```
# Build Folders (you can keep bin if you'd like, to store dlls and pdbs)
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# mstest test results
TestResults

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.log
*.tlog
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried with this but it still seems to include the files in this folder: `D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Release\Meeting .56FC3877.tlog`

Comment: if they are already part of the repository, delete them first and commit/push the change

Comment: side question if I may: What about existing commits on the bitbucket website? Can they kind of be purged so that these ignored files are no longer even in the history?

Comment: sorry, but I have no idea. I setup the ignores always in first step

Comment: @magicandre1981, why .tlog is not included in your .gitignore?

Comment: The better question is, why is .tlog not included in the gitignore.io template for Visual Studio?